# Cedet completion menu

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs24

I am using emacs24. I would like to get the auto-completion experience that I get in e.g. eclipse. That is:
- on pressing e.g. C-RETURN, to get a menu, which updates on-the-fly as I type the name of the method; I would also like to navigate with the arrows through the choices
- On clicking a completion from the menu, I would like to have something like a tooltip with the documentation of the specific method, if found

semantic-ia-complete-symbol opens a new buffer. semantic-ia-complete-symbol-menu does not come  by default with emacs (built-in). Even if it did, it does not update itself on the fly, and I don't have the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer all your questions, but it is a start:

```
;; shows a menu by clicking CTRL-RETURN
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<return>") 'auto-complete)

;; allow to navigate the autocompletion menu with <up> and <down>
(setq ac-use-menu-map t)
(define-key ac-menu-map "<down>" 'ac-next)
(define-key ac-menu-map "<up>" 'ac-previous)
```